# How to find particular word from a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

cases: & required output

```
1) string1 = "Multi Axle Volvo SemiSleeper" => o/p true
2) string2 = "Multi Axle Volvo Semi-Sleeper" => o/p true
3) string3 = "Multi Axle Volvo Semisleeper" => o/p true
4) string4 = "Multi Axle Volvo Semi Sleeper" => o/p true
5) string5 = "Multi Axle Volvo Semi sleeper" => o/p true
6) string6 = "Multi Axle Volvo sleeper" => o/p true
7) string7 = "Multi Axle Volvo sleeper" => o/p true
8) string8 = "Multi Axle Volvo" => o/p false
```

From all the strings i need to check that '**sleeper**' is present or not with one logic.

example: string1 = "Multi Axle Volvo SemiSleeper" in this 'sleeper' word is present? then true else false....like this i wrote 8 cases....

```
string1.split(' ').map(&:upcase).include?(SLEEPER) => case failing
string1.split(' ').map(&:upcase).include?(SLEEPER) => case Passing
```

Any help/suggestion ...

Comment: What code are you using to accomplish this now?  How is that code failing?

Comment: Suppose one string is there string1 = "Multi Axle Volvo SemiSleeper", i need to check 'sleeper' is present in this string or not?

Comment: I guess you have not learned about regular expressions yet? If so, then read http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html - if there is anything you do not understand please update the question.

Comment: Search for ruby regular expressions, go to the first link on google. And do some reasearch next time :)

Comment: I see you have added some new code based on the accepted answer. This is useful, it might be possible to fix for you. However, I think you are missing some detail, so I cannot see what is wrong. Could you add a little bit more of your code, so other people can get same error result as you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to check for upper and lower case 'sleeper'.

```
str = "Multi Axle Volvo SemiSleeper"
str.downcase.include?('sleeper')
=> true
```

Comment: Please don't give code answers for poor questions, it keeps them alive on the site. The OP will also be better served with links to documentation and advice on how to learn the language, not code fixes which keep them dependent on asking similar questions on SO.

Comment: @dax: Because (IMO) the question *should* be closed and AGS has enough rep to know this and act upon it.

Comment: i agree with you about not answering bad questions...but downvote the question rather than a reasonable answer

Comment: @dax: Perhaps take this to meta, but I am going with my definition of "This answer is not useful", as explained in my earlier comment it is not useful because it clogs up SO, and *also* does not really help the OP.

Comment: fair enough...i don't fundamentally disagree with you, and you're also right that it's not helping the OP